# Grep in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, busybox

I just recently updated my Ubuntu VM to 14.04 and before this I could run the grep command

```
grep -nr "piece of text"
```

or any other grep command for that matter and it would finish in 2-10 seconds in the directory I was working on. Now for some reason (no idea if this was caused by the update) running any grep command in the same dir I was working in just seems to hang there (idk if it does complete because I don't want to wait over a min or so for a search to happen) instead of showing my results. Any idea of what's happening or what I can do and try to fix it?

Comment: from where do you execute your grep ? it might be very slow since it recurse in directories.

Comment: or after upgrade it is not using gnu grep but some busybox one ? cd /tmp; grep -nr "truc"; => using gnu grep -> it returns. using busybox : cd /tmp; busybox grep -nr "truc"; : it reads STDIN.

Comment: which grep : what does it returns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't specifying the files to grep, so it's trying to read STDIN. I think you wanted

```
grep -nr "piece of text" *
```

Note the asterisk is [globbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to all files in the current path.

Comment: on my debian testing : cd /tmp; echo "truc" >truc; grep -nr "truc"; returns "truc:1:truc" . this might by due to option "-r" that is recursive in directories and then don't care about STDIN ?

Comment: getting grep code from (git://git.savannah.gnu.org/grep.git) : else if (directories == RECURSE_DIRECTORIES && prepended < last_recursive)
    {
      /* Grep through ".", omitting leading "./" from diagnostics.  */
      filename_prefix_len = 2;
      status = grep_command_line_arg (".");
    } => i guess it runs on '.'

Comment: Elliot you were right, IDK why I was able to use grep without specifying the dir's to search in before but specifying where to search did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry I am a newbie here. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

which `grep` are you using ? `-r` option default to '.' directory in gnu case

```
which grep :
/bin/grep --version
/bin/grep (GNU grep) 2.18)
...
this is gnu grep :

echo "truc" >/tmp/truc

cd /tmp; grep -nr "truc";
```

using gnu grep -> it search recursively files in . of current directory ( here in `/tmp` ) and displays them containing "truc"

if `/bin/grep --version` is busybox :

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-8) multi-call binary.
```

Usage:

```
grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFEz] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN.../-f FILE [FILE]...
```

using busybox : `cd /tmp; busybox grep -nr "truc";`

wait indefinitely that you type content of file on STDIN ( stop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ).

it reads STDIN as a file ( not even caring that `-n` indicates a directory recursion ).

Answer (score 1):

As others answered, and as [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) or [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) documentation tells, you need to specify some file to the standard `grep` command. (But *GNU* `grep` defaults to current directory `.` if `-r`  is given without a directory name; however if `-r` is not given at all, `grep`  defaults to read `-` i.e. the *stdin*).

BTW, I would also recommend the [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) utility, packaged as the [`ack-grep` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ack-grep) on Ubuntu or Debian. It does not need any files (default is the source code files under current directory) and it avoids useless non-source files (version control or object files...):

```
 ack "piece of text"
```

Also, under [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), you can use `M-x grep`

Comment: see my comment , from grep code i guess it defaults to '.' for -r option. then it doesn't not necessarily requires a FILE even if documentation states otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I have heard of ack, didn't know if it was better or not